# LASSO objective function in b'Qb + c'b form

Tags: r, optimization, cplex, quadratic-programming

I'm trying to minimize the LASSO objective function using the Rcplex package in R. The help page of Rcplex shows that the objective function should be written in b'Qb + c'b form. How do I rewrite [image: formula] To something that has the form b'Qb +c'b or is there some different way to implement the LASSO objective function into Rcplex?

Comment: Are you sure Quadratic programming is the right algorithm for this? It would be more straightforward to implement this using gradient descent.

Comment: That would be a bit of an annoyance (e.g. l1 needs to be smoothed somehow). Any very good reason to this? In what context? As said: that's not a very good/specialized way of solving the problem; and if that is research / a prototype, you could start with the mostly automatic [cvx-based approach](https://cvxr.rbind.io/post/examples/cvxr_intro/), where all those things get done for you (at some cost; but we already established: you won't beat specialized algorithms). Some reformulations of this would also target SOCP instead of QP (expected to be a better way).